# How to solve JQ processing as multiple dictionaries if document has an array and JQ filter uses group_by?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON document

```json
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "description": "Component 1",
    "due": "20211122T183000Z",
    "entry": "20211119T181735Z",
    "modified": "20211119T181735Z",
    "project": "product1",
    "status": "pending",
    "uuid": "55bf0497-208c-492a-8f76-bb692d48afaa",
    "tags": [
      "abc",
      "123"
    ],
    "urgency": 13.9699
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "description": "Component 2",
    "due": "20211129T183000Z",
    "entry": "20211130T045620Z",
    "modified": "20211130T045620Z",
    "project": "product2",
    "status": "pending",
    "uuid": "d57eb8f7-e5ec-497c-ac47-f1cf34b005db",
    "tags": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ],
    "urgency": 14.0151
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "description": "Component 3",
    "due": "20211202T183000Z",
    "entry": "20211130T121529Z",
    "completed": "20211130T123915Z",
    "project": "product3",
    "status": "pending",
    "uuid": "9f15e6a4-5cef-4b0f-915b-fc916ab152c7",
    "tags": [
      "xyz",
      "676"
    ],
    "urgency": 14.0096
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "description": "Component 4",
    "due": "20211202T183000Z",
    "entry": "20211130T122537Z",
    "pending": "20211130T122537Z",
    "project": "product1",
    "status": "pending",
    "uuid": "91c9ec76-42a7-4ebc-9649-b3a12027feb1",
    "tags": [
      "def"
    ],
    "urgency": 13.9096
  }
]
```

I have written below JQ filter to parse the JSON, the expected output is not to generate multiple dictionaries.

```
group_by(.project,.status)  
         | .[] 
         | { project: .[0].project , status: .[0].status , 
             description: [{"\(.[].description)" : (.[].tags | join(";"))}] }
```

After applying the filter, i get the below output with `multiple dictionaries` because of the `tags` array

```
{
  "project": "product1",
  "status": "pending",
  "description": [
    {
      "Component 1": "abc;123"
    },
    {
      "Component 1": "def"
    },
    {
      "Component 4": "abc;123"
    },
    {
      "Component 4": "def"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "project": "product2",
  "status": "completed",
  "description": [
    {
      "Component 2": "foo;bar"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "project": "product3",
  "status": "completed",
  "description": [
    {
      "Component 3": "xyz;676"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output I am expecting is without `multiple dictionaries` as below

```
{
  "project": "product1",
  "status": "pending",
  "description": [
    {
      "Component 1": "abc;123"
    },
    {
      "Component 4": "def"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "project": "product2",
  "status": "completed",
  "description": [
    {
      "Component 2": "foo;bar"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "project": "product3",
  "status": "completed",
  "description": [
    {
      "Component 3": "xyz;676"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I generate the above-expected output using JQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One similar option to yours would be

```
jq 'group_by(.project)[] 
             | { project: .[0].project, status:.[0].status, "description": [.[] 
             | { (.description) : .tags|join(";") } ] }'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yYXkS9DI0E)</kbd>

Comment: modified slightly and was able to get the required output. 
```shell 
jq '{ task:[ group_by(.project,.status)[] | { project: .[0].project, status:.[0].status, "description": [.[] | { desc: (.description) , tags: .tags|join(";"),"urgency":.urgency,priority:.priority } ] }] }' 
/path
```

Answer (score 1):

To just bring together `.description` and `.tags` use

```sh
jq '.[] | del(.description, .tags) + ({(.description): .tags | join(";")})'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZL5erhQ2Bw)

To also group by `.project` and just consider `.project`, `.status` and an array with the `.description` and `.tags` from above, go

```sh
jq '
  group_by(.project)[]
  | (first | {project, status})
  + {description: map({(.description): .tags | join(";")})}
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ykhbMqlpAD)